# Activeadmin where to place this variable code from my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, activeadmin

I have created a nice little view but it has some code in it that I would normally place in a controller. I have tried making a controller for the model but Active Admin ignores it. I have tried a small controller do block inside the Active Admin resource file which just caused errors. Where can I place this so that the supply_company Active Admin controller can access it?

```
<% supply_company_id = SupplyCompany.find(params[:id])
 @ccarray = CompanyScore.where(supply_company_id: supply_company_id).pluck(:score) %>
```

The below partial works fine (yes i know ugly) but I can seem to find the spot to place the logic for it to be rendered in ActiveAdmin.

render partial

**/app/views/admin/_supply_company_ratings.html.erb**

```
<%
   supply_company_id = SupplyCompany.find(params[:id])
 @ccarray = CompanyScore.where(supply_company_id: supply_company_id).pluck(:score) %>

 <% @ccarrayaverage = (@ccarray.inject 0, :+) / @ccarray.count%>
<% @ccarraypercent = (@ccarrayaverage.to_f)/10*100 %>
<% @divpercent = @ccarraypercent.to_s %>

Average Score
  <h1> <%= @ccarrayaverage %></h1>


Total Score
  <h1>  <%= @ccarray.inject 0, :+ %></h1>

Total Votes
<h1> <%= @ccarray.count %> </h1>

Percent
<h1> <%= @ccarraypercent %> </h1>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar  progress-bar-custom" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%=@divpercent%>"
       aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<%=@divpercent%>%">
    <%= @divpercent.to_s %>% Percent
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe because its in a sidebar its not reading the activeadmin controller block.
**/app/admin/supply_company.rb**

```
   show title: :company_name do
     attributes_table do
       row :company_name

     end
     end


  sidebar "Products", only: :show do
    attributes_table_for supply_company do

     # row rating_for SupplyCompany, "price"
        row  :company_name
      row "Ratings" do

         render  'supply_company_ratings'
      end

      row :products do |pt|
        pt.products.collect {|c| link_to c.product_name.capitalize, admin_products_path + "\/" + c.id.to_s}.join(", ").html_safe
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the code into AA controller block is right idea.

```
controller do
  def index
    supply_company_id = SupplyCompany.find(params[:id]).id # note .id part - it makes sure you pass an id not the whole object in the query below
    @ccarray = CompanyScore.where(supply_company_id: supply_company_id).pluck(:score)
  end
end
```

Comment: Cheers. Dam it I had forgotten the def index inside the controller block. Thank you

Comment: Sorry tried it an it still will not work. I dont kow if its because is two different models or what. If i place it in the Activeadmin suppy_company.rb it just wont grab the array.

Comment: Yeah . as index block ::undefined method `inject' for nil:NilClass . I'm adding this to a sidebar on the show view. As a show block undefined local variable or method `supply_company' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::SidebarSection:0xa3a3040>

Comment: where do you use `supply_company`? as I understand, there is only  `supply_company_id` variable..

Comment: The only place is as part of the sidebar in activeadmin. see above for the the show code that also includes a sidebar. If i place it like this but the above doesn't as a sidebar. ' show title: :company_name do
     attributes_table do
       row :company_name
       row "Ratings" do

         render  'supply_company_ratings'
       end
       row :products do |pt|
         pt.products.collect {|c| link_to c.product_name.capitalize, admin_products_path + "\/" + c.id.to_s}.join(", ").html_safe
       end
     end
     end'

Comment: Will mark as correct as it is a correct answer. Just cant seem to get it to work as a sidebar. :-)